# How to make a template function in C++ to define a bit representation of any type

Tags: c++, templates, std, sfinae, bit-representation

```cpp
template<typename T>
std::string bit_representation(T &&type) {
    uint8_t data[sizeof(T)];
    if constexpr (std::is_copy_constructible_v<T>) {
        T tmp(type);
        std::memcpy(&data, &tmp, sizeof(T));
    } else if (std::is_move_constructible_v<T>) {
        T tmp(std::move(type));
        std::memcpy(&data, &tmp, sizeof(T));
    }

    auto get_byte_repr = [](uint8_t byte) -> std::string {
        std::string s;
        constexpr size_t byte_size = sizeof(uint8_t) * 8;
        s.resize(byte_size);
        for (int i = byte_size - 1; i >= 0; --i) {
            s[i] = ((byte & 1) == 1) ? '1' : '0';
            byte >>= 1;
        }
        return s;
    };
    std::string result;

    for (int i = sizeof(T) - 1; i >= 0; --i) {
        result += get_byte_repr(data[i]);
    }
    return result;
}
```

I wrote simple `bit_representation` function, for simple types all good but i want to write uniform template function for pass `std::initializer_list<T>` too.

```cpp
    uint8_t u8 = 0xAF;
    std::cout << bit_representation(u8) << std::endl; // 10101111 ok
    std::cout << bit_representation((uint8_t) 0xAF) << std::endl; // 10101111 ok
    std::cout << bit_representation((short) 0xAF) << std::endl; // 0000000010101111 ok
    double d = 2.56;
    // 0100000000000100011110101110000101000111101011100001010001111011 = d its ok iee-754
    std::cout << bit_representation(d) << std::endl;
#pragma pack(1)
    struct {
        bool c = true;
        int a = 0x00FF00FF;
    } name;
#pragma pop()
    // 0000000011111111000000001111111100000001 // really ok
    std::cout << bit_representation(name) << std::endl; //  ok
    std::cout << bit_representation(true) << std::endl; // 00000001 ok
    std:cout << bit_representation({1,2,3,4}) << std::endl; /* error candidate template ignored: couldn't infer template argument 'T'
std::string bit_representation(T &&type) {*/
```

But `bit_representation({1,2,3,4})` not working..
I thing need write SFINAE wrapper for compile time detecting if type is `initializer_list<T>`.

I expecting `bit_representation({1,2,3,4})` -> std::initializer_list to memory repr ->
`00000000000000000000000000000001000000000000000000000000000000100000000000000000000000000000001100000000000000000000000000000100`

How to deduce std::inititalizer_list parameters and write special logic for this.

Comment: what is the meaning of "not working" ?

Comment: `{1,2,3,4}` has no type that could be deduced.

Comment: error: no matching function for call to 'bit_representation'
    `bit_representation({1,2,3,4});`

Comment: please post a [mcve]. If I want to write an answer I will have to start from this: https://godbolt.org/z/Gzqh53K8j, but you do have code that compiles (apart from one error for `{1,2,3,4}`), please post it

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number i cant deduce std::initializer_list<T> in compile time..

Comment: Note initialization list is actually a pointer and size, so this `std::memcpy` will do something you do not expect.

Comment: Add an overload that takes a C-style array.

Answer (score 1):

`std::initializer_list` is somewhat special. In particular (from [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/initializer_list)):

> A `std::initializer_list` object is automatically constructed when:
>
> - a braced-init-list is used to list-initialize an object, where the corresponding constructor accepts an `std::initializer_list` parameter
> - a braced-init-list is used as the right operand of assignment or as a function call argument, and the corresponding assignment operator/function accepts an `std::initializer_list` parameter
> - a braced-init-list is bound to auto, including in a ranged for loop

`bit_representation({1,2,3,4})`  is none of this. `{1,2,3,4}` is not a `std::initializer_list`. Only in certain contexts `{1,2,3,4}` causes a `std::initializer_list` to be automatically constructed. In all other contexts `{1,2,3,4}` has no type that could be deduced.

You can call the function with a `std::initializer_list` like this:

```
bit_representation(std::initializer_list<int>{1,2,3,4});
```

Moreover, consider that any object can be viewed as an array of bytes. No copying to an array is needed. This is due to the exception for `char`, `byte` and `unsigned char` for strict aliasing, as explained here: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/reinterpret_cast. It is also unclear why your function does not use its argument `type` (rather misleading name) directly but makes another unnecessary copy `tmp` before copying to the array.

This might give you a better start (untested):

```
std::string bit_representation(const T& t) {
       unsigned char* byte_repr = reinterpret_cast<unsigned char*>(&t);
       for (size_t i=0; i< sizeof(T); ++i) {
            byte_repr[i]; // <- i-th byte of t
            // ...
```

Comment: Thanx i write new function

Comment: its crazy but its working, i add overloaded definition
```cpp
template<typename T>
std::string bit_representation(std::initializer_list<T> ilist) {
    std::string result;
    for (const auto item: ilist) {
        result += bit_representation(item);
    }
    return result;
}
```

Comment: He could overload the stream operator to std::byte and only return a span of std::byte.
The c++ standard also defines [std::as_bytes](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/span/as_bytes)

Comment: @vanyabeat what is crazy?

Comment: @FabianKeßler yes there are nicer facilites in c++20. However, I assume c++17 if nothing else tagged, also because I am not fluent with c++20. And I have the impression that OP wants something self-made, I might be wrong though

Comment: @vanyabeat consider the comment by Marek above. With the code in the comment you create the string representation of the integers contained in the `std::initializer_list` not the representation of the `std::initializer_list`. This is same difference as the bytes of eg a `std::string` and the bytes of the characters it contains. Your function will do the former for the `std::string`

Comment: @FabianKeßler @463035818_is_not_a_number after simple 
overload, `bit_representation({1, 2, 3, 4})` working and
`bit_representation({uint8_t(0xAB), uint8_t(0x0F), uint8_t(0xAA)})` -> `101010110000111110101010`

Comment: @yanyabeat you must understand the differnce between "byte resprentation of `std::initalizer_list<int>{1,2,3,4}`" and "byte representation of the 4 integers 1,2,3 and 4". Your overload does the latter. Me and others aassumed the first because that would consistent with what your function does eg to a `std::string("abc")`. It will not produce the byte representation of a, b and c

Comment: @yanyabeat concering "crazy" consider that before c++11 it was impossible to make `bit_representation({1,2,3,4})` work at all. The language had to change, and it was made possible by the automatic construction of a `std::initializer_list` as described in the quote in the answer.

Answer (score 0):

In the end, this solution turned out, but I'm not sure if it's right
**SOLUTION**

```cpp
template<typename T>
std::string bit_representation(T &&type) {
    auto ptr = reinterpret_cast<const uint8_t *>(&type);
    auto get_byte_repr = [](uint8_t byte) -> std::string {
        std::string s;
        constexpr size_t byte_size = sizeof(uint8_t) * 8;
        s.resize(byte_size);
        for (int i = byte_size - 1; i >= 0; --i) {
            s[i] = ((byte & 1) == 1) ? '1' : '0';
            byte >>= 1;
        }
        return s;
    };
    std::string result;
    for (int i = sizeof(T) - 1; i >= 0; --i) {
        result += get_byte_repr(ptr[i]);
    }
    return result;
}

template<typename T>
std::string bit_representation(std::initializer_list<T> ilist) {
    std::string result;
    for (const auto item: ilist) {
        result += bit_representation(item);
    }
    return result;
}
```

**Outputs**

```cpp
    unsigned short carr[] = {0xDEAD, 0xBEEF};
    struct mZ {
        mZ(uint8_t value) {
            auto ptr = reinterpret_cast<uint8_t *>(this);
            std::fill(ptr, ptr + 1, value);
        }

        mZ() = delete;

        mZ(const mZ &o) = delete;

        mZ(mZ &&o) = default;

        uint8_t a: 1;
        uint8_t b: 1;
        uint8_t c: 1;
        uint8_t d: 1;
        uint8_t e: 1;
        uint8_t f: 1;
        uint8_t g: 1;
        uint8_t h: 1;
    };
    
    /*1111111110101010*/
    std::cout << bit_representation((short) 0xFFAA) << std::endl;
    /*11111110*/
    std::cout << bit_representation(mZ(254)) << std::endl;
    /*00000000000000000000000000000001000000000000000000000000000000100000000000000000000000000000001100000000000000000000000000000100*/
    std::cout << bit_representation({1, 2, 3, 4}) << std::endl;
    /*10111110111011111101111010101101*/
    std::cout << bit_representation(carr) << std::endl;
```

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number